# Why does the code output only 'Have a nice day?' In spite of inputting Friday and declaring the given string?

Tags: c, string-comparison, fgets, c-strings, strcmp

I am writing a c program to print specific statements if current day is Friday using if-else statement. What is  the error involved?

I've tried using integer values for the same code and it works, but when i  equate n as Friday the output shows else part only.

```
char s[10]="Friday";
char n[6];
printf("Enter a day:\n");
scanf("%s",n); //n is string
if(n==s)
    printf("Have a nice weekend!");
else
    printf("Have a nice day!");
```

I expect the output for "Friday" to be "Have a nice weekend!", but the output is "Have a nice day!" for any input.

Comment: Your comparison is comparing two *pointers* that will never the equal. Any decent book or tutorial should have taught you about [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp).

Comment: BTW, the array `n` is not big enough to hold the string `"Friday"`.

Comment: Also, beware of buffer overflow. `char n[6]` is too short for any unabbreviated English names of days of the week.

Comment: I think this is a dup, but I'm on mobile. Will find it for you when I can

Comment: Also note that n only has room for five characters plus the terminating null character. "Friday" with its 6 letters will already overflow it, not to mention "Wednesday"! Reserve more space with e.g. `char n[11]` and then use `scanf("%10s", n)` or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a function like strcmp to compare char arrays in `C`.

```
if(strcmp(s, n) == 0) {
    printf("Have a nice weekend!");
}
```

When you use the `==` operator you are comparing addresses (or sometimes pointers), not string literal values.

Also as pointed out above (pun intended) an array in `C` needs space for the null terminating character.

Comment: I am new to C language and not well versed in strcmp function. I used switch statement for the problem and it was working fine but had problem with if-else statement. Much thanks.

Comment: @NiveshP good work, you are learning. strcmp is a basic C function widely used to compare strings. It's perfectly good to use as needed.

Answer (score 2):

For starters you should enlarge the array becuase the string literal `"Friday"` can not fit into the array.

For example

```
char n[10];
```

Secondly instead of `scanf` use the standard function `fgets` because `scanf` such as it is written in your program is unsafe.

For example

```
fgets( n, sizeof( n ), stdin );
```

You can remove the trailing new line character the following way

```
n[ strcspn( n, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

To do that you have to include the header `<string.h>`.

In this statement

```
if(n==s)
```

there are compared addresses of first characters of the strings. You need to use standard string function `strcmp` to compare the strings themselves instead of the pointers. For example

```
if ( strcmp( n, s ) == 0 )
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s = "Friday";
    char day[10];

    printf( "Enter a day: " );

    fgets( day, sizeof( day ), stdin );

    day[ strcspn( day, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

    if ( strcmp( day, s ) == 0 )
    {
        printf( "Have a nice weekend!" );
    }       
    else
    {
        printf( "Have a nice day!" );   
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter a day: Friday
Have a nice weekend!
```

Comment: Why should i use fgets instead of scanf? Why is scanf unsafe? Because fgets can read from open file while scanf reads only that of standard file?

Comment: @NiveshP Because the user can enter more characters then the size of the array used in scanf. fgets allows to enter exactly the number of characters that is specified by the second argument. And you indeed entered more characters (including the terminating zero) when the array had size equal to 6. This invokes undefined behavior of the program.

Comment: So fgets gets the exact number of characters to be inputted. Much thanks mate.